# appcompat dependency error on project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

Hi I am trying to build my old project nearly two year old and also i am using eclipse but when i add depedency to my project it shows appcombat v7 jar file missing HERE are screen shot

and in my project properties it shows appcombat..../bin appcombat v7.jar file is missing so i copied jar file from sdk and paste it after that my project which shows **!** now shows error * also appcombat is showing error please help me guys here is screen shot of that

In appcombat under resource->values-v21->style_base->

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
           parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton">
    </style>
```

it shows error  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.

error log is:

```
[2015-09-08 11:38:37 - Raftaar_Jyotish] D:\Gaurav\Work\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:137: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-09-08 11:38:37 - Raftaar_Jyotish] 
[2015-09-08 11:38:37 - Raftaar_Jyotish] D:\Gaurav\Work\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:134: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-09-08 11:38:37 - Raftaar_Jyotish] 
[2015-09-08 11:38:37 - Raftaar_Jyotish] D:\Gaurav\Work\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:135: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-09-08 11:38:37 - Raftaar_Jyotish] 
[2015-09-08 11:38:37 - Raftaar_Jyotish] D:\Gaurav\Work\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:144: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
[2015-09-08 11:38:37 - Raftaar_Jyotish] 
[2015-09-08 11:38:37 - Raftaar_Jyotish] D:\Gaurav\Work\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:148: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
[2015-09-08 11:38:37 - Raftaar_Jyotish] ............
```

many times

Comment: you mean `appcompat` right? and you need to fix your image link.

Comment: yes i cant upload image due to repo

Comment: Check your build target.Make sure that a Build Target is checked. Sometimes you need to uncheck it, select a different API, apply settings, and then again select the API that was originally selected.

Comment: not working tried building with api 19, 20, 21 but still shows error also cleaned project after build change

Comment: @GauravMehra delete this appcompat from workspace. create a new project so a new appcompat will be created. use the new appcompat

Answer (score 0):

You should import Appcompat as a project, then in properties > android set it to a library (check islibrary), and don't forget to set the appropriate project build target. 
After that go to your project and from properties  > android add that project as a library

Comment: it is that way from start all my dependencies are is library

Comment: What is the build target for the Appcompat project? And which version are you using?

Comment: right now its api 19 and also i am using same build target for my project but also tried others api

Comment: sdk->extra->android ->support->v7->appcombat so it imported from here so it is v7

Comment: Appcompat libraries have another version number you find it in the sdk manager under extras to the left of Android support library. It's most likely 22 or 22.1 or 23

Comment: Yes,  but which revision?

Comment: android support library shows 23.0.1 and android support repository shows 19 these are under rev but under api these are blank

Comment: Thanks for helping continuously but the error is still there

Comment: Have you changed the build target and cleaned the project?

Comment: yes done i have tried api 20 and right now its 20 viz 4.4w.2 and the error still the same

Comment: You Have to make it 23 for the library

Comment: library is 23.0.1 installed

Comment: In the project properties > android, what is the project build target?

Comment: android 5.0.1 both in project and appcombat

Comment: You should make it android 6.0 for Appcompat